# Does not paint Graphics in Java

Tags: java, swing

Hey guys i am trying to build custom shapes in Java and for some reason it doesn't paint them into my Canvas.

I have created a Class:

```
public class MyCircleCanvas extends JComponent{
    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(new Color(150, 150, 150));

        //g2d.fillRect(30, 20, 50, 50);
        //g2d.fillRect(120, 20, 90, 60);
        //g2d.fillRoundRect(250, 20, 70, 60, 25, 25);

        //g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 100, 80, 100));
        //g2d.fillArc(120, 130, 110, 100, 5, 150);
        g2d.fillOval(270, 130, 50, 50);   
   } 

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }    

}
```

Then in My JFrame i Call this Class:

```
private void initComponents() {
        createMenu();
        createToolBar();
        createCenterPanel();
        //createCanvas();
    }

private void createCanvas() {
        //c = new Canvas();
        //c.setBackground(Color.white);
        // this.add(c);
        add(new MyCircleCanvas());
    }
```

This works fine. BUT when i try to call the method `createCanvas()` from an ActionListener of a JButton it does not create the shape i want. Any suggestions???

Comment: The `createCanvas()` method should instead be called `drawShape()` and use a canvas that has already been added to the GUI.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: how do i add the new MyCircleCanvas() into the canvas and get the rectangle then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should overwrite the `paint` method instead of the `paintComponent`. To add the `MyCircleCanvas`ses to a graphical user interface, I created a `JPanel` with a `BoxLayout`. In this panel, the newly added `MyCircleCanvas`ses are added vertically.

Make sure to overwrite the `getPreferredSize` method because else the `MyCircleCanvas will not have a visible size when adding it to the user interface.

Also the `pack` methods makes sure that the `JFrame` is properly sized to include the new `MyCircleCanvas`s.

```
    public class MyCircleCanvas extends JComponent {
    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(new Color(150, 150, 150));
        g2d.fillOval(25, 25, 50, 50);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }
}
```

And this frame:

```
public class CircleCanvasFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JPanel circlePanel = new JPanel();

    public CircleCanvasFrame() {
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400, 400);
        circlePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(circlePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JButton button = new JButton("add a circle canvas");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(circlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CircleCanvasFrame();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        circlePanel.add(new MyCircleCanvas());
        pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that works fine. But the thing is how to add the new MyCircleCanvas into the JFrame from an ActionListener of a JButton???

Comment: @KostasDrakonakis, I edited the example above to include addition of more panels using a button.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are positioning the Oval too far to be seen. Make the location closer to origin.

```
private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g2d.fillOval(0, 0, 50, 50);   
   }
```

Here is a rough idea of how it could be done after this:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JButton button = new JButton("test");
                frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        MyCircleCanvas circle = new MyCircleCanvas();
                        frame.add(circle);
                        frame.pack();

                    }
                });

                frame.add(button);
                frame.setSize(100,100);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```